# Localized Display Name for English languages not working

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, plist

This is really strange iOS problem.

I want to localise my current English application for the USA, by adding en_US.

By default, when localizing a file, it creates an English.lproj, and I add an en_US.lproj, assuming that would be used by en_US users. It isn't.

It looks like iOS takes the English.lproj language as a priority over the region specific, according to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-130599 where it states ***"The same application on the iPhone would look only in the en.lproj directory."***

Therefore I implemented this workaround which does the trick : [iPhone App Localization - English problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/3311899#3311899)

However, now I want to localise the CFBundleDisplayName for the en_US application, but I'm getting hit with the same problem. It ignores my en_US localized infoPlist.strings and takes the English infoPlist.strings value.

Is this a huge oversight by Apple? What are my options? Create en_ localized versions for all english speaking regions to ensure they get the English, and US get's en_US?

Answer (score 0):

In IOS region based localization is not possible. In IOS English means en_US,British English means en_GB. For other english based region you can used right thing :)