# iOS localization with region (de_LU)

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, region

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone App Localization - English problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems)

I am working on an App for iOS devices. I made it available for English (en) and German (de). That works fine with localization. Now I want to create a specified localization for German with region Luxemburg: German (Luxemburg) or de_LU.
I added it into my Localizable.strings but nothing happened... I deleted the cache, I reinstall the app serval times: Nothing. He ignores that.

My iPhone is configured with the German language and Luxemburg as region.

Where is the problem? Or is it impossible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, to localize into that culture you should have a `de-LU.lproj` folder, is that the case?

> A typical application has at least one strings file per localization, that is, one strings file in each of the bundle’s .lproj subdirectories. The name of the default strings file is Localizable.strings but you can create strings files with any file name you choose.

*(Quoting [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html))*

If you're using Xcode 4, just go to project settings, Info tab, then add your localization from there, it will setup the project accordingly for you.

Also note that Apple recommends that you save strings files using the `UTF-16` encoding

Comment: Yes, I am using Xcode 4 and yes there is a de-LU.lproj file. But it doesn't show the content I want. He shows everytime the localization German (de). When I delete the German one, he shows me the placeholders. (the English localization file is currently empty) But the German - Luxemburg (de-LU) localization does nothing...

Comment: And are your `de-LU.lproj` files correctly in Resources copy build phase? You can also check the .app content that build produced.

Comment: Do not hesitate to delete from xcode project files (only references) and re-add them to clean up references that might be messed up

Comment: I tried everythink. I cleaned the project, I reinstalled the app, I deleted all localizable files and created them new, nothing. He ignores the de-LU localization. Maybe my the configuration is false? Could you check that? http://bit.ly/hip4O9

Comment: looks ok to me, maybe you should check at runtime : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/ChoosingLocalizations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002397-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Check for region & language in code. If language German & region Luxemburg then keep new key for localization.And initialize that key in German language localized file. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe that supporting dialects is currently impossible in iOS 4.