# How to test localization "portuguese brazil"?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I wonder How to trigger the localization language portuguese-brazil in iphone? (or simulator is all right)?
that's, how can I test Portuguese-Brazil localization on iphone?

I found there's only Portuguese and Portuguese(Portugal) in the international setting but unfortunately neither could be the answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have set the international setting to (language== Portuguese,  region==Brazil), but still not work, can anyone point me a way?

Comment: This answer to another question was helpful for me to solve the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/3311899#3311899

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am Portuguese, to trigger those, you should put the language as Portuguese. If it's not working on your case, might be a problem related with the code. Try doing the following:

- Keep only 1 version of the Localized.strings file as the Portuguese version, remove everything else (just for testing).

Comment: Thanks a lot,Jacky. I have use the same way for testing, but I'm still wonder a perfect way when I 'm testing for a release ipa. I have updated my questions, your suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i had the same problem and i just solved it.

Use "Portuguese" instead "Portuguese-Brazil" in your project, and your Portuguese language of device should work fine.

Here is the problem:

I was trying to set the portuguese language with Portuguese-Brazil at the "+" when i selected the project file, and when i changed my device and my simulator (used both to test) language to portuguese (once there is no portuguese-brazil), the text was coming from the default language (english), what means it was not working.

I tried deleting "Portuguese-Brazil" and adding "Portuguese", and it worked when i changed my devices to portuguese language;

I think that is a bug in XCode, that language "Portuguese-Brazil", since the device has no language like that in Settings > General > International> Language of devices, only "Portuguese"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking at the wrong setting. To change the language in iOS, go to Settings > General > International > Language. There is also Settings > General > International > Region Format but this setting controls things such as date, time and number formats (i.e. locale formats, not localization)

When you change the Language setting, even in the simulator, you will see that the iOS user interface will have changed to the new language. If you then launch your app and you don't see it localized as you expect (assuming that of course you added the localized resources in that language), then something is wrong!

Comment: Thanks your help! I have set the international setting to (language== Portuguese,  region==Brazil), but still not work, do I make any thing wrong?