# French Canadian Localization

Tags: ios, ipad, localizable.strings

When I create a localization for fr-CA and then switch my iPad to use that language and region, it still uses my English localizable.strings file. If I just create an fr localization and switch the iPad, however, it works fine. Any ideas on what might be going wrong? Are my settings on the iPad correct (see screenshot)? Any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html

Under “Language and Locale IDs” it says the following:

> **Important** In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script
>   information into account when looking for localized resources; only
>   the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project
>   includes language-specific project directories with both a language
>   and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle
>   interfaces in OS X do support region designators in language-specific
>   project directories.

Comment: Does this mean that separate localization for French / French-Canadian are not supported in iOS? Is this still true?

Comment: Look at this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/25483554#25483554