# iOS : How deal with specific resources for US residents ( en_US )?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I'm working on an iOS app that must have a different name and some different
 images for US residents (different brand name).

I defined an en-US.lproj rep but it's never used. When I simulate an US resident I have : [[NSLocale currentLocale] locale localeIdentifier] => 'en_US', but the en.lproj is used.
I tried to change (in Xcode) the 'Localization native development region' but it doesn't change anything.

I don't have any problem with the french localization.

I could do it with code but not for the app name or the Default.png.

How to make the en-US.lproj work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a part of my problem with this answer :

[iPhone App Localization - English problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/3311899#3311899)

But as "iPhone localisations (or is that localizations?) do not take any notice of the Region the user sets", I can do nothing for the BundleDisplayName or the Default.png.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: You should also know that if you change the language/region settings you may have to restart the phone to get the app work with the correct region settings!!!

i fixed it by setting the base language to english and in the main.m i called:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier], nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```