# iOS Bundle Display Name - en-GB and en-US

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, locale

**Context:**

We are developing an iOS app that has the word Math/Maths in it. This needs to change depending if the device's language is English or British English.

**Problem:**

So, I have two InfoPlist.string files for `en-GB` and `en-US` and in the iOS simulator the App displays either an `en-GB` or `en-US` App name depending if the language was set to English or British English. However, it's very glitchy (sometimes working, sometimes not) and according to Apple's Dev guide it's not (or shouldn't be) possible! That's not to say the doc isn't outdated or wrong.

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF

> **Important**: In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script
>   information into account when looking for localized resources; only
>   the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project
>   includes language-specific project directories with both a language
>   and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle
>   interfaces in OS X do support region designators in language-specific
>   project directories.

Am I on a wild goose chase and it's not actually possible or it is, and just very buggy? If it is possible, how?

Comment: Are you testing on two different devices or just changing one device from US to UK during testing?

Comment: So far just testing in the simulator, changing the language between English and British English.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is not possible automatically. For localizeng the os looks for the language, not for the region. So it just takes into account the en. But the good news is that there is a indirect solution which requires little effort: check the approved answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/3311899#3311899).

Comment: So @Nikos M the name of the app as displayed in the app store and on the home screen cannot be regionalized, but within the app it can?

Comment: In the app store it can, you can provide localizations for all the info you put in itunes connect.

Comment: What about the app's name on the launch screen, @nikos-m?

Comment: The app name no, it should be the same for the engilish regions.