# Localisation Language settings iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added two language localisation in my iOS project

1. Spanish(es)
2. Argentinean Spanish (es-AR)

In my iPhone language setting i have checked 'esponal' but it loads the Spanish(es) strings.

Now i need to check the Argentinean Spanish too. So what settings i need to do in my iPhone to check Argentinean Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the iPhone region settings to Argentina.

Edit:
Actually, it look slike this is not supported on iOS:

> **Important:** In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF

Comment: I have changed the region to Argentina, but still the app loads the Normal Spanish

Comment: "Important: In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories". https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144-BBCEGGFF

Comment: What does it mean? There is an option in xcode for adding Argentinean spanish. So how can i test the added language localisation texts?

Comment: From what I understand, this feature only works on OSX, you cannot use it on iOS

Comment: Then we cannot use Argentinean Spanish (es-AR) for iphone apps? Is there is any possibility or any other way i can support the Argentanian language for my iphone app?

Comment: Look here, sounds a bit like a hack though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems

Comment: Awesome.. Is apple accepts my app if i add this code in main.m?

Comment: It looks like it is using only official API so no reason to be rejected