# iOS 12 - NSLocale issue

Tags: ios, ios12, nslocale

If you are using iOS >= 12 and set device language and region to France (fr_FR) [Device settings IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eWle.png) and fetch current locale from the code:

```
[NSLocale currentLocale]
```

or

```
[[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale] localeIdentifier]
```

result will be en_FR.

Keep in mind that app has localization for France [Localizable.strings IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3g6.png) and info.plist contains

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>fr</string>
    <string>it</string>
    <string>de</string>
</array>
```

Why is this happening? Did I miss something?
Same approach is working on iOS < 12.

Comment: I suggest submitting a bug report to Apple.

Comment: locale identifier is a combination of two things: [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) __language__ code, and an [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) __region__ code, in you case `en_FR` says the language is English but the region code is France – which is a totally valid localisation information, there is no bug to be reported.

Comment: Solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/14357315/5292385