# How to get my Localization differentiate between English US and English UK in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am setting the culture for my app manually to en-GB, but for iOS simulator doesn't seem to take the Region part of my culture, it will show me only the values under my default RESX file which is in US English. Also While I tried to use es-MX as a Culture, it was defaulting to English, too. I had to create an extra copy of my Strings.en-MX.resx file called Strings.en.resx to finally having to work. But In this case I do want to differentiate US and UK (or GB)

Answer (score 0):

iPhone localisations (or is that localizations?) do not take any notice of the Region the user sets (ie, UK, Aus, NZ). There is only one "English" language translation available by default. However, you can hack around with things to force it to use a different translation setting.

Here is the detailed info, you can take a look:

[iPhone App Localization - English problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308519/iphone-app-localization-english-problems/3311899#3311899)